# "INSTEAD OF" in MySQL trigger, converted from SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm in the process of converting some SQL Server triggers to MySQL, and am running into some syntax issues. The rest of the database schema and objects were converted using the AWS Schema Conversion Tool, as I'm migrating a SQL Server database to Aurora RDS MySQL. Here's an example of a trigger I'm having trouble converting:

```
-- Create the UpdateAUD trigger on the new table.
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdateAUD] ON [dbo].[AUD]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR( 'Audit rows for AUD cannot be updated!', -1, 0 );
    ROLLBACK;
  END
END;
```

The code that I've tried looks like:

```
DELIMITER $$
-- Create the UpdateAUD trigger on the new table.
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdateAUD 
AFTER UPDATE
ON dbo.AUD FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set msg = ('Audit rows for AUD cannot be updated!');
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
    ROLLBACK;
END$$
```

First, does `AFTER` work to replace `INSTEAD OF`? Secondly, MySQL workbench is having an issue with the RAISERROR, which I've looked up workarounds for. However the error I'm getting is around theh `msg` variable where it's saying `Unknown system variable 'msg'`

Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest reading the documentation for each product to determine how parts of the syntax work. And don't tag SQL Server as you are looking for someone with MySQL expertise.

Comment: This is something you can better handle by denying UPDATE permissions for the selected users, a much better option than triggers. In both SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: I tagged SQL in there too since the original syntax is coming from a SQL Server db and its functionality needs to be duplicated in MySQL

Comment: Please use the [tag:sql] tag for the SQL language, independent of any implementation, and [tag:sql-server] for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Don't tag SQL Server because an SQL Server expert is not necessarily a MySQL expert. And rather than saying I need this functionality as implemented in SQL Server, explain your actual requirements independent of RBDMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be a BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER, so that the UPDATE is interupted

You could also

```
REVOKE UPDATE ON AUD FROM '*'@'localhost';
```

and so nobody could UPDATE the table anymore

> ```
> CREATE TABLE AUD (id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO AUD VALUES(1)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER UpdateAUD 
> BEFORE UPDATE
> ON AUD FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     set @msg := 'Audit rows for AUD cannot be updated!';
>     signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = @msg;
> END
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE AUD SET  id = 1 WHERE id = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> Audit rows for AUD cannot be updated!
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b2341dbc8dfbf147fb59f4a3be7c4055)*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up revising to

```
DELIMITER $$
-- Create the UpdateAUD trigger on the new table.
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.UpdateAUD  
BEFORE UPDATE
ON dbo.AUD FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Audit rows for AUD cannot be updated!';
END$$
```

Per documentation, there's no need for `ROWCOUNT` since `FOR EACH ROW` should handle that. As far as the `ROLLBACK` goes, I checked https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html and saw that it should be handled as well.

Does this look like a good conversion from the original MS-SQL posted at the top?

Comment: it a copy of mine as you can see it works

Comment: Yes I marked yours as the answer and upvoted